# Junit Test case run in STS successfully although can not run through Jmeter.

Tags: java, maven, jmeter

I have a Java project in Spring tools editor. When I run test cases in spring it gets executed. Although When I export it in jar and put in Jmeter/lib/junit. and pick junit request sampler in Jmeter it fails with

> 018-11-30 14:06:30,854 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler.getClassInstance(JUnitSampler.java:534)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_junit.jar:5.0 r1840935]    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler.initializeTestObject(JUnitSampler.java:658)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_junit.jar:5.0 r1840935]    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JUnitSampler.threadStarted(JUnitSampler.java:646)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_junit.jar:5.0 r1840935]    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:762)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]     at
>   org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994)
>   ~[jorphan.jar:5.0 r1840935]   at
>   org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977)
>   ~[jorphan.jar:5.0 r1840935]   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:730)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:718)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181] Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.autodesk.acmtest.config.env.EnvConfigs.loadFromPropertiesFile(EnvConfigs.java:38)
>   ~[acm_test.jar:?]     at
>   com.autodesk.acmtest.config.env.EnvConfigs.loadFromSystemProperties(EnvConfigs.java:30)
>   ~[acm_test.jar:?]     at
>   com.autodesk.acmtest.config.Configs.getEnvConfig(Configs.java:34)
>   ~[acm_test.jar:?]     at
>   com.autodesk.acmtest.cases.BaseTests.(BaseTests.java:11)
>   ~[acm_test.jar:?]     ... 14 more 2018-11-30 14:06:30,858 INFO
>   o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
>   2018-11-30 14:06:30,859 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar:
>   setRunning(false, *local*)

I am using Jmeter 5.0 and Java 1.8. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the error cause:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.autodesk.acmtest.config.env.EnvConfigs.loadFromPropertiesFile(EnvConfigs.java:38) ~[acm_test.jar:?] at

My expectation is that you forgot to copy some ".properties" file along with your JUnit test configuration, if you use relative paths - most probably you should put the file to JMeter's "bin" folder.

Alternatively looking into `EnvConfigs.loadFromSystemProperties` line you can perform the configuration in *system.properties* file (it lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) or provide the values via `-D` command line arguments like:

```
jmeter -Dparameter1=value1 -Dparameter2=value2 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

More information:

- [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks for reply back. When I am running that it throws a warning WARN o.a.j.p.j.s.JUnitSampler: ClassNotFoundException::

Comment: You need to add all the dependencies of your JUnit tests to [JMeter classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath). Alternatively you can build your JUnit tests as a [Uber Jar](https://imagej.net/Uber-JAR). Check out [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) for general recommendations and troubleshooting tips.